# A tensor of rank $3$ satisfies $T_{ijk}=T_{jik}$ and $T_{ijk}=-T_{ikj}$. Show that $T_{ijk}=0$

Tags: tensors

> A tensor of rank $3$ satisfies $T_{ijk}=T_{jik}$ and
>   $T_{ijk}=-T_{ikj}$. Show that $T_{ijk}=0$

I really don't know what we can use to show this. All I am able to do is rearrange the dummy indices to get a few more equations but they're of no use.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: you might find it useful to aim at $T_{ijk}=-T_{ijk}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using both given statements you have $$T_{ijk}=-T_{kji}$$
Using the first statement and then the second statement successively, these are equal to $$-T_{jki}=+T_{ikj}=-T_{ijk}$$

Hence $$T_{ijk}=-T_{ijk}=0$$